# Angular DatePicker Not Correctly Set to Current Date

Tags: angular

I have a datepicker component which needs to have the default value set to todays date only when it's name matches a certain current date elements name. The current date initally shows as expected when the element drops. But as zoon as the element is focused in on the date is taken away and doesn't come back when you unfocus. This is messing up the entire functionality of this component right now.

this is the code for the date element

```
      <mat-label>{{ config.templateData?.label }}</mat-label>

      <mat-icon [style.margin-right.px]="6" *ngIf="config.templateData?.prefix" matPrefix>{{

        config.templateData?.prefix }}</mat-icon>

      <input matInput id="{{config?.templateData?.UID}}"

             aria-label="Date" role="textbox"

             [required]="config.templateData?.required || false"

             [formControl]="date"

             [matDatepicker]="picker"

             [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"

             [disabled] = "true"

             [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate">

      <mat-hint *ngIf="config.templateData?.hint">

        {{config.templateData?.hint}}

      </mat-hint>

      <mat-datepicker-toggle  matSuffix [for]="picker">

        <mat-icon *ngIf="config.templateData?.suffix" matDatepickerToggleIcon>{{getValueAsString(config.templateData?.suffix)}}</mat-icon>

        readonly

      </mat-datepicker-toggle>

      <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>

    </mat-form-field>
```

code to get todays date

```
date = new FormControl(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
date = new Date();

By setting:
date = new FormControl(new Date());

Your are resetting the control, that is why it is changing.

Comment: Hey I just tried that but with the current code and the changes to the date line i got error. TS2740: Type "Date" is missing the following properties from 'FormControl': defaultvalue, setvalue, patchvalue, reset, and 54 more. If you have any more suggestions for that im listneing.

Comment: Hi Julian do have a codeine of this code I could look at?